# How to override "default" navigation bar?

Tags: ios, storyboard, interface-builder, uinavigationbar

On my iOS application, I have the following view controllers navigation scheme on my storyboard

> Navigation Controller -> ViewController A -> ViewController B

I'm able to customize the navigation bar on `View Controller A` but custom navigation bar I designed on interface builder, doesn't show up for `View Controller B`. It only shows up the "back" button.

Can I define a custom navigation bar for "inner" views on interface builder? I know I could do it programatically, but if I can avoid it, the better.

Comment: Define custom navigation bar. Like title and barbuttonitems or whole new view?

Comment: @beyowulf: I added a navigation bar from tool box to `View Controller B`, then I changed the title and added a right button. Nothingof that is reflected.

Comment: Read @bensarz answer. You don't need to drag out a navigation bar. If your navigation controller is properly set up one is already provided in all of it's view controller's views. You must however set each one up individually. Give each it's own title and own barbuttonitems.

Comment: @beyowulf: understood. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you may be missing an important element in your understanding.
The `UINavigationBar` owned by the `UINavigationController` is merely a container for each view controller's `UINavigationItem`. Use this navigation item to add/remove buttons that are specific to each view controller.

Using your own example:

> `UINavigationController` (displays each view controller's navigation item inside its navigation bar) -> `UIViewController` A (includes `UINavigationItem` A, which has its own buttons) -> `UIViewController` B (includes `UINavigationItem` B, which has its own buttons)

If you want to hide the back button you can do so by adding the following line inside each view controller or in your view controller's superclass:

`self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true`

If you want all view controllers to have the same buttons, you're probably better off creating a `UIViewController` base class and add the proper buttons to the navigation item programmatically. Make sure all your view controllers inherit from this new subclass.

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 Thanks!. So there is no chance to edit navigation bar for each view controller using interface builder? (using the schema I posted on my question)

Comment: Yes, you can do it in interface builder. Just drag a navigation item from the bottom right into your view controller. Then add the buttons that you want your view controller to display inside the navigation item. You may have to hide the back button programmatically though.